# Compare data using SQL in one table

Tags: sql, mysqli

I have one table with the following 2 columns and data:

```
filename, source
a.txt, 1
a.txt, 2
b.txt, 1
c.txt, 1
c.txt, 2
```

Can someone please tell me the SQL query I would use to show the difference between the filename in source 1 and 2?

In the example above, the difference would be "b.txt"

Thanks!!!

Comment: I really don't understand what you want here

Comment: please elaborate with an example. As far as i understand table1 has some filenames and table2 has some filenames, and what difference should the query highlight

Comment: i updated the example. there is only one table and yes i would like to show the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can try usin sub query to select all filename in source 1 which is *not co-exist* in source 2 :

```
SELECT 
    filename
FROM MyTable t
WHERE t.source = 1
    AND t.filename NOT IN 
            (SELECT filename FROM MyTable WHERE source = 2)
```